# Capybara with Selenium: Can't click on hidden element

Tags: ruby, selenium, knockout.js, capybara

I have a situation in my view where a clickable icon is only visible when it's containing div is hovered over (using Knockout JS, SCSS) . Something like this:

## HTML

```
<div id="button_div">
   <i id="icon" data-bind="click: dosomething"></i>
</div>
```

## SCSS

```
i {
  display: none;
}

#button_div:hover {
   i {
      display: block;
   }
}
```

Everything works fine on the page, but I can't seem to figure out how to click the element in Capybara. I've tried adding the :visible symbol to the method, but with no luck:

```
find('#icon', visible: false).click
```

This gives me the a "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError" error.

Using:

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
```

Gives me the exact same error

I've also tried using a Selenium Action such as:

```
button_div_element = find('#button_div').native
button_element = find('#button', visible: false).native
page.driver.browser.action.move_to(button_div_element).click(button_element).perform
```

While this doesn't throw an error, it also doesn't click the button.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some painstaking trial and error, I managed to find a solution that worked

```
button_div = find("#button_div_id").native
icon = find("#icon_id").native
page.driver.browser.action.move_to(button_div, :right_by => -50).click.perform
icon.click
```

Not sure why I had to manually tell Capybara to go left by 50px, but that seems to have done the trick.

Also, I added the following line to my setup code:

```
page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
```

This makes sure the window is maximized before running the test. I'm not 100% sure, but this might have also had something to do with the fix.

Answer (score 4):

Capybara is designed to emulate a user so you can't click on a non-visible element because a user couldn't.  You should, however, be able to replicate a users actions to make the element visible and then click it

```
find('#button_div').hover
find('#icon').click
```

if that doesn't raise an error but also doesn't appear to click the button try putting a short sleep between the two actions since you may have an animated appearance which can cause clicks to miss items

Comment: This seems like it should work, but it doesn't (at least for me). I get an "element not found" error when I try to click on the icon.

Comment: Hmm, this exact behavior is tested for in capybara - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/2a51b817b355f6c1a5e95a471a87f1a492562e55/lib/capybara/spec/session/node_spec.rb#L266 - not sure what is different in your app

Comment: @nmg49 what other CSS is applied to the icon

Comment: I am having same kind of problem. I can find element by using find('css_selector') and when using the path i find element in browser then it leads to correct element. but when i try to click on it by find('css_selector').click then it does not click on it. It can also not be a problem of doing all this very quickly as I am debugging it using byebug and doing all this stuff so page was loaded completely. Any idea what can be the problem in this case?

Comment: @waqas If you have an issue create a new question with enough detail about the issue (HTML, code you've tried, details of exactly what you mean by "does not click" (error, no response,...), etc) for someone to answer.  Don't ask new questions in the answers of previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.execute_script()` as below :-

```
button_div_element = find('#button_div').native
button_element = find('#button', visible: false).native
page.driver.browser.action.move_to(button_div_element).perform
page.driver.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button_element)
```

Hope it will work...:)